# Stitching flat tiles of different heights together

Tags: java, algorithm, lwjgl, tile, heightmap

### The Problem

I have a 3D world in which I have created completely flat tiles with differing heights. What I want to do is stitch the vertices of the tiles together such that they meet somewhere in the middle and create seamless terrain. (e.g. (sideview) from _¯ to _/¯ )

[Here's a picture of what the tiles currently look like (the floating tile has an arrow texture on it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO1KO.png)

Currently, I store the map data in a text file containing the x position, z position, height, and texture. I create the heightmap in my code like this:

```
    public static BufferedImage createHeightmapImage(int[][] vertexHeights) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(Heightmap.HEIGHTMAP_RESOLUTION, Heightmap.HEIGHTMAP_RESOLUTION, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        int a = (255);
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
                int r = (vertexHeights[x][y]);
                int g = (vertexHeights[x][y]);
                int b = (vertexHeights[x][y]);
                int p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                img.setRGB(x, y, p);
            }
        }
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(180), img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        return img = op.filter(img, null);
    }
```

It takes in the (currently 4) vertex heights, which would all be the same for a flat tile. I rotate the image 180 degrees so that its north edge is the same direction as what I designated north as.

My map loading code is as follows:

```
    public GameMap loadMap(String name) {
        ArrayList<MapData> mapData = getSortedMap(name);

        List<Tile> tileList = new ArrayList<Tile>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mapData.size(); i++) {
            int worldX = mapData.get(i).getX();
            int worldZ = mapData.get(i).getZ();
            String texture = mapData.get(i).getTexture();
            int heightmapValue = mapData.get(i).getHeight();
            TileTexture tileTexture = new TileTexture(loadTexture(texture));
            Heightmap heightmap = Tile.generateFlatHeightmap(heightmapValue);
            Tile tile = new Tile(worldX, worldZ, this, tileTexture, heightmap);
            tileList.add(tile);
        }
        GameMap map = new GameMap(name, tileList);
        return map;
    }

    public ArrayList<MapData> getSortedMap(String name) {
        ArrayList<MapData> data = FileUtils.getMapData(FileUtils.loadAsStringList("res/map/" + name + ".map"));
        return data;
    }
```

The getSortedMap function just loads the map data into an ArrayList and sorts it given x and z such that I can read and load the terrain from the top left to the bottom right.

I have tried to create a larger heightmap image and take subimages from it for each tile, but that ends up creating terrain that is jagged and not connected at the edges or corners.

I have also tried to alter the heightmaps after creation of the world to meet the vertex heights in the middle on each edge and corner, but I can't find a way of doing it without creating a whole mess of code that only works for one heightmap resolution. The resolution I'm currently using is 2x2, although I was considering increasing it if it didn't suit my needs.

Comment: I don't know how your `Tile` class looks like but can't you just check in your heightmap for each tile what neighbouring tiles it has and just replace its vertices with the ones provided by those tiles? Of course to avoid two neighbouring tiles changing each other you can mark a tile as changed once you adjust its vertices and then for the next (neighbouring) tiles do the same vertex adjustment but only for those vertices that have unchanged neighbouring tiles.

Comment: No, that's not possible with my current implementation. I do have a getSurroundingTiles method in another class, but then I run into the messy issue of getting the matching vertices for the 3 tiles next to the center tile's appropriate vertex [(something like this)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/145238056/Images/Screenshots/shot_160909_023103.png). Unless I'm missing something and it's actually easier than that.